Book involving a massive alien spaceship under the arctic, horror/thriller
I'm trying to find a book that I read several years ago as a digital book from Amazon's free Kindle program.
The premise is a bunch of scientists/military types travel to the Arctic or Antarctica and end up investigating a massive alien ship that's buried in the ice.
There are a number of different alien species aboard that get loose, and it is revealed that the main alien species responsible has essentially been on a safari collecting different species from around the solar system.
There are short descriptions of the aliens hunting these species on different planets in the solar system.
I recall that the species they find and retrieve from Venus are essentially acidic blobs, which ultimately destroy the base and kill one of the main characters.
The book ends with the spaceship being activated by one of the main characters, who, as it flies away, kills the villain (who I believe was a mutated human or something similar) and leaves for space.
This isn't The Thing, Ice Rift, Ice Station, or any other book as part of a series to my knowledge.
Thank you. I've been trying for days to find this book, and it seems to have up and vanished.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Your reputation points will also carry over to future contributions. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

This could be Anomaly, a novel from 2018 by Hugo Navikov.
As the OP recalls, the plot deals with an alien spaceship found buried under the Antarctic, containing a wide range of alien lifeforms. According to the goodreads blurb:

An Above-Top-Secret project brings military brass, elite commandos,
ice-drilling experts, and abducted scientists to investigate a
100-mile-long 'gravitational anomaly' half a mile under the West
Antarctic Ice Shelf.
Their a spaceship buried for millions of years, home to a menagerie of
alien and prehistoric horrors that could be unleashed on Earth and end
every life on it.

There are a lot of different lifeforms, but my memory of the Venusians coincides with the description in the question, and is confirmed by one of the goodreads reviews:

acid blobs from Venus know how to hunt people and take out load
bearing pylons

